# Pandas- Concatenating two columns of string lists

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, concatenation

I've got an.. interesting data frame that comes from a database.  The data frame has two columns, which are lists of strings.  I need to concat the values in these two lists, to create a new column of lists.  For example:

```
data = [ 
    {'id': 1, 'l1': ['Luke', 'Han'], 'l2': ['Skywalker', 'Solo']}, 
    {'id': 2, 'l1': ['Darth', 'Kylo'], 'l2': ['Vader', 'Ren']},
    {'id': 3, 'l1': [], 'l2': []}
]                                                                                                                                                                
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Notice the third row has no values.  You can also assume that `l1` and `l2` are of the same length.
And I need to concat the values in l1 and l2 (with a space between), e.g.:

```
result = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': ['Luke Skywalker', 'Han Solo']},
    {'id': 2, 'name': ['Darth Vader', 'Kylo Ren']},
    {'id': 3, 'name': []}
]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Comment: Will the elements of the name column always be either a list of two strings or an empty list?

Comment: No.. The elements could be a list of any length (though both `l1` and `l2` are guaranteed to be the same length)

Answer (score 2):

You you use `dict comprehension` and `' '.join` in combination with `zip` to iterate over your dataset, for example, this:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = [ 
    {'id': 1, 'l1': ['Luke', 'Han'], 'l2': ['Skywalker', 'Solo']}, 
    {'id': 2, 'l1': ['Darth', 'Kylo'], 'l2': ['Vader', 'Ren']},
    {'id': 3, 'l1': [], 'l2': []}
]                                                                                                                                                                
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

result = [
    {
        'id': row['id'], 
        'name': [' '.join(l1_l2) for l1_l2 in zip(row['l1'], row['l2'])]
    } for row in data
]

print(pd.DataFrame(result))
>>>
   id                        name
0   1  [Luke Skywalker, Han Solo]
1   2     [Darth Vader, Kylo Ren]
2   3                          []
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you to where you want: assuming you only have two columns (if you have more just add one of those ' '+df.iloc[j,3 &or 4 &or...][i])

```
Voila =[]
for j in range(len(df)):
    Voila.append([df.iloc[j,1][i]+ ' '+df.iloc[j,2][i] for i in range(len(df. 
                                                                loc[j,'l1']))])
df['Voila'] = Voila
```